# Python Django Login required mixin

Tags: python, django

trying to use django braces login mixin required in views
i dont have a databases to store session i 'am using

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
```

without login when i type a url (eg: 8000/dashboard it direct me to login)
but when i trying to login in it is not redirecting me to my dashboard page

please help

```
class Login(CsrfExemptMixin, View):

    template_name = 'login.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        try:
            if request.session['access_token']:
                if request.session['path_previous']:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.session['path_previous'])
                else:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/')
        except:
            return render_to_response( self.template_name, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.POST.get('uName','')
        password = request.POST.get('pwd','')

        login_obj = LoginDataView()
        login_response = login_obj.get(request,username,password)


        if login_response.status_code == 200: 

            request.session['access_token'] = login_response.json()['access_token']
            request.session.set_expiry(10000)

            print "hihihihihi"
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/')
        else:
            context = {
            'bad_string' : "Please provide correct login credentials",
            }
            return render_to_response( self.template_name, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))








class GetDashboardView(LoginRequiredMixin,CsrfExemptMixin, View):

login_url = '/login/'
#redirect_field_name = "hollaback"
raise_exception = False
template_name = 'index.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    tpl = tpl_lookup.get_template(self.template_name)
    #return render_to_response( self.template_name, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return HttpResponse(tpl.render())
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for `LoginDataView` please? You seem to be doing the login view in a very non-django way. You're not using forms, you're not using the built-in `django.contrib.auth.views.login`. I'm assuming the `LoginDataView` at least calls `authenticate` and `login`, but can't be sure without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use [django-registration](http://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or so. If you will use it add to your urls.py:

```
url(r'^accounts/register$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=
    RegistrationFormUniqueEmail), name='registration_register'),
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

`registration.backends.default.urls` contains broken names, so including `django.contrib.auth.urls` fix it.

If you will use gjango-social-auth, add line below in urls.py

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('social_auth.urls')),
```

and fix datatime JSON serialization by adding following line in settings.py

```
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'
```

It is not full tutorial or so on, it is just some of ways out.